# What feature of the Facebook API are Branchout using?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It seems like BranchOut are the only Facebook application which can still get the attention of me and my friends. What features of the Facebook API are they using to reach my homepage with 5 new requests per day? How have they avoided being banned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BranchOut is a Facebook partner and as such they get special access, including customized requests that show application context.  Where most apps get text like "Bill Smith sent you a request in [app name]", BranchOut gets requests like "Bill Smith wants you to join his professional network".  Unfortunately, BranchOut's strategies cannot easily be replicated.